# How to round specific parts of symbolic expression using sympy?

Tags: sympy

I'm new to python and sympy and am a little lost. What's the easiest way to round all of the numbers except 0.268994781998603, 0.525103332486078, and 0.2357023740927390 in equations that look like this:

```
   0.268994781998603*x**0.24883285 + 0.525103332486078*exp(-Abs(2.011218*x - 1.101318)) + 0.2357023740927390*x**0.25234357
```

Would it have to do with using `srepr`?

Ultimately, I'd like to round the exponents `0.24883285` and `0.25234357` to `.25` so `sympy` will combine those respective terms when using `sympify`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is keep the high precision Float but round the lower precision ones. You can discriminated based on the associated precision. I defined 'eq' to be the equation you gave above:

```
>>> for i in sorted(eq.atoms(Float)):
...   print(i._prec, i)
...
27 -1.101318
53 0.235702374092739
30 0.24883285
30 0.25234357
53 0.268994781998603
53 0.525103332486078
27 2.011218
```

So let's get the lower precision floats in a list:

```
>>> lp = [i for i in eq.atoms(Float) if i._prec <= 30]
```

And let's define a replacement dictionary that rounds to two decimal places:

```
>>> reps = {k: k.round(2) for k in lp}
```

And now use it to replace those Floats in `eq`

```
>>> eq.subs(reps)
>>> eq.subs(reps)
0.504697156091342*x**0.25 + 0.525103332486078*exp(-Abs(2.01*x - 1.1))
```

The exponents, now being the same, caused the two terms to join.

If you rounded at two significant figures you would get:

```
>>> reps = {k: k.n(2) for k in lp}
>>> eq.subs(reps)
0.268994781998603*x**0.25 + 0.235702374092739*x**0.25 + 0.525103332486078*exp(-Abs(2.0*x - 1.1))
```

The terms don't join because these 2-sig-fig values are not exactly the same. Conversion to a string and re-sympification will work, however. (But I would stick to the `round` version.)

```
>>> eq2 = _
>>> from sympy import S
>>> S(str(eq2))
0.504697156091342*x**0.25 + 0.525103332486078*exp(-Abs(2.0*x - 1.1))
```

To just replace Floats in a given region of the expression there are lots of ways to parse up the expression: coefficients of Mul, constant terms of Add, etc... In the comments below you say that you want to make the change in `sin`, `sign`, `exp` and exponents (`Pow`) so something like this can work:

```
>>> from sympy import sin, sign, exp, Pow
>>> eq.replace(
...   lambda x: isinstance(x, (sin, sign, exp, Pow)),
...   lambda x: x.xreplace(dict([(i,i.round(2)) for i in x.atoms(Float)])))
0.504697156091342*x**0.25 + 0.525103332486078*exp(-Abs(2.01*x - 1.1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I like the simplicity of your solution, however the precision of the floats could change a lot in my program. Ultimately, I just want to round anything in exponents or within the four functions my program can produce: `sin(), sign(), exp(), and 1/(1+exp())`. That way, simpify will combine something like `.2*1/(exp(1.1*x) + 0.9) + 1.31*1/(exp(x) + 1.0)` without losing precision in the leading terms (.2 and 1.31). At the same time, my expression could containt `3.21xy+5.23125xy`, which I wouldn't want to round at all.

Comment: Then a smart `replace`, maybe like this, would work: `eq.replace(lambda x: isinstance(x, (sin, sign, exp, Pow)), lambda x: x.xreplace(dict([(i,i.round(2)) for i in x.atoms(Float)])))`

Comment: Thank you! One more question: Using a similar technique, how would I replace any number in the equation that is near zero with zero? For instance, anything less than .01 would get replaced with 0.